# Ubuntuでの1ディレクトリあたりのファイル数上限、容量上限はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Ubuntuでの1ディレクトリあたりのファイル数上限、容量上限はあるのでしょうか？
ある場合は教えていただけますでしょうか。

現在CMSを構築していて記事のサムネイル画像を記事IDと紐付けて保存している状況でして、
上記のようなことが気になりました。
何十万という記事が書かれ、その分サムネイルが設定される場合は問題が生じるのか気になっております。
Ubuntu 14.04 LTSを使用しております。

Comment: ファイル数や容量のの上限は使っているファイルシステムに依存しています

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ちなみに僕の使用しているファイルシステムはext4で、総ファイル数は232 - 1(4,294,967,295)でディレクトリあたりのファイル数は制限なしでした。
大手のブログサービスは日付などでディレクトリを分けていましたが、僕の場合は分けなくてもいいのかなと思いました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

クォータを設定していない前提であれば ファイル数がinodeの最大値に達するもしくは マウントポイントの最大容量が上限になります。

性能については、ディレクトリ内のファイル郡をリストアップする場合や 検索するような場合はファイルが多いほど負荷が上がり性能が劣化します。ファイル名がわかっていて直接ファイルを読み書き出来る場合は性能劣化は見られません。

CMSはわかりませんが、記事とサムネイル画像の紐付をDB等で管理されていて ファイル名がわかっているのであればファイルの読み書きの性能劣化はないと思います。

ディレクトリ内のファイルを検索して画像を探すような場合は CPU負荷、メモリ使用量、ディスクIOが増え、応答時間は長くなるでしょう。

またShellでのファイル操作するが面倒になります。(ls が終わらない、ファイル名の展開が終わらない、引数が多すぎてコマンドに渡せない、など)

どのくらいの数で性能が劣化するかは、お使いの環境によって違いますので性能測定を実施して適切な数を見極めるといいと思います。

以下、どこまでファイルを作成できるか実験した結果です。

環境

- VirtualBox VM

  - 1024 MB Memory
  - Processor 6
  - Sotrage Controller : IDE
  - Disk 1 16.00GB   main.vdi (/dev/sda)
  - Disk 2 100.00 GB test.vdi (/dev/sdb)
- Centos7.1

100GB の ext4 ファイルシステム構築後 Inodes の値は 10 使用、6,553,590 がフリーでした。

```
FileSystem           Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1           6553600       10   6553590    1% /var/test
```

1,000,000,000 Bytes のファイルを split で 10バイトずつ分割し 一億個のファイル作成を試みますが途中でエラー終了しました。

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.dat bs=1000 count=1000000

# split -a 8 -b 10 zero.dat
split: xaaaoiwra: No space left on device
```

ファイルの数はIFreeで表示された値と同じでした。なお、数えている間 ls コマンドは CPUが30-100%くらいメモリは85%くらい消費した状態で、1時間以上かかりました。

```
# time ls -1 | wc -l
6553590

real    68m27.671s
user    1m2.893s
sys     21m7.490s
```

IUse% は 100% 使用中となり、これ以上ファイルを作成できない状態だとわかります。

```
# df -i
Filesystem    Inodes    IUsed   IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1    6553600  6553600    100% /var/test
```

ディスクの容量は 27GB Used ですのでまだ余裕があります。

```
# df -h
Filesystem    Size  Used  Avail  Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      99G   27G    68G   29% /var/test
```

ファイル名を直接指定して読み書きした場合、目立った遅延はありませんでした。

```
# time od -x xaaaaxxxx
00000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000012

real     0m0.169s
user     0m0.000s
sys      0m0.008s
```

Shellのファイル名の補完や正規表現の展開は恐ろしく時間がかかりますし 引数が多すぎて rm xa* などはエラーになりました。

ファイルの削除は次のように行いました。

```
# ls -1 | egrep -e '^xa*$' |xargs rm
```

Comment: ext4ならデフォルトで有効のようですが、ext3の場合HTree indexが有効になっていないとファイル名を指定してのアクセスも同様に遅くなりそうです。 http://moimoitei.blogspot.jp/2006/07/ext3-htree-option-is-safty.html

Comment: 実験した結果も併せてわかりやすいご説明ありがとうございます。画像の読み書きは特に問題なさそうということが分かり安心しました。シェルでの ll などの操作が重くなるとのことですので検討したいと思います。

Answer (score 6):

おそらく、ファイルシステム単位で利用可能な `i-node` の最大数の事をおっしゃられているのかと思いますが、例えば以下の様にして確認する事ができます。

```
$ df -i .
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda7      1831424 78532 1752892    5% /home
```

特に説明しなくても表示されている内容はお分かりいただけるかと思います。

また、`tune2fs` コマンドでも同等の結果を得ることができます。

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda7 | grep -i inode
                 :
Inode count:              1831424
Free inodes:              1750561
                 :
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
IUseが 2%だったのでまだ余裕そうではありますが、パフォーマンスの面で何か悪影響がでないかと心配しております

Answer (score 1):

実質的に上限はないと思って構いません。ただし、上限が無いからと言って数万ものファイルを置くような設計にすればすぐにパフォーマンストラブルに見舞われると思います。

まず、ディレクトリが管理できるファイル数ですが、ディレクトリの実態はファイル名と所在するi-nodeの番号を記入したファイルです。管理するファイルが多くなるほど、記録したファイルの名前が長いほどディレクトリのサイズも大きくなっていきます。そういう意味では一つのディレクトリが管理できる上限はファイルシステムで作成できる最大のファイルサイズになるまで、ということになります。しかし、現実的には数TB位のストレージ全部をディレクトリで使うわけにもいかず、もちろんメモリにも読み込めず、全く実用になりません。

プロバイダのブログが日付でディレクトリを分けているのは一つのディレクトリのファイルが多くならないよう設計されているのです。おおくても1ディレクトリあたり数千に止めるよう設計される方がいいと思います。これでも、トラブルがあると表示さえできず、パニックになりますが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。例えば
    /test/test1.txt
 というファイルがあって /test/ ディレクトリに数十万のファイルがある場合 /test/ のディレクトリ情報(内包しているファイル名)ごとメモリに読み込むことは不可能であるため実用にならないという認識で合っていますでしょうか？